# iframe session being lost

Tags: php, session, iframe

I'm having a very frustrating issue.  I have one website (site A) that has an iframe of another site I own (site B).  When I go to site B myself in the browser I can move around the site and not be logged outgoing between pages.  However, when I have site B in the iframe of site A, after logging in, if you try going to another page it logs out because it doesn't have a session anymore.  I tried a workaround by passing the session_id as a get var in this situation which isn't ideal but now it doesn't work in all situations.  I want to be able to retain the session and can't figure out what the issue is.  I have tried making changes for cross-domain rights to allow it but this didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?